# What is the role of symbols `-` in line TEST_PROFILE="${1-}" and ${TEST_PROFILE-}?

Tags: bash, shell

I am reading `nvm` shell script and meet something I don’t understand, please help

```
nvm_profile_is_bash_or_zsh() {
  local TEST_PROFILE
  TEST_PROFILE="${1-}"
  case "${TEST_PROFILE-}" in
    *"/.bashrc" | *"/.bash_profile" | *"/.zshrc")
      return
    ;;
    *)
      return 1
    ;;
  esac
}
```

What is the role of symbols `-` in line `TEST_PROFILE="${1-}"` and `${TEST_PROFILE-}`?

Comment: See also [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: BTW, all-caps names are used for variables that can change behavior of the shell or other POSIX-specified commands, whereas the POSIX sh standard reserves variables with at least one lower-case character for application use and guarantees that they won't have unintended effects on the shell's behavior. (That guarantee only holds for POSIX-compliant shells, though, so zsh doesn't honor it).

Comment: ...on that convention, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a single namespace (modifying a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable).